# Set custom nav back button with multiple navigation controllers

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I have a tab bar controller that has 5 tabs, each with a navigation controller embedded in. There are times where I need to display a view controller from another tab.

I am overriding the stock back button text `< BACK` to just have it say `<`, which I do using

```
let backItem = UIBarButtonItem()
backItem.title = ""
navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backItem
```

However, when I load a view controller from a different tab bar (with a different navigation controller), I can't figure out how to remove the `< BACK` from the supplementary navigation controller so I can just display the button as `<`. Putting the above code in `prepareForSegue:` works with one nav controller, but not when there is a second one. Thanks a lot, any insight is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The back button that you see when a view controller is pushed onto the navigation controller's stack belongs, not to the pushed view controller, but to the *previous* view controller, the one that *was* showing *before* the push.

If *that* view controller says:

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = 
    UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .Plain, target: nil, action: nil)
```

... then when a view controller is pushed on top of it, the back button will show no title.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response @matt. So I understand that setting the prior view controller in `prepareForSegue:` sets the back button for the view controller about to be pushed. In my situation, I have a collectionview from another view controller as a subview of this parent view controller. I put the code to set the `backButton.title = ""` in `prepareForSegue:` for both the parent view controller as well as in the child view controller. I'm not sure where else the new view controller would come from where it wouldn't change the title to "". Any ideas? Thanks again!

Comment: Why do this in "prepareForSegue"? If it's a feature of the view controller, you would do it "viewDidLoad".

Comment: This did the trick, it works correctly in `viewDidLoad:`. I saw that it should be in `prepareForSegue:`, but this looks to be wrong. Thanks again, really appreciate it!!